# Should a missing Path Parameter in a REST call result in 400 or 404?

Tags: java, rest, http, server, jersey

If there are 2 usecase for REST Service,

1. `GET` `http://localhost:8080/resource/{id}`  ==> that returns all the
   data of the resource as per "id"

   So if client requests without "id" path parameter like `GET`
   `http://localhost:8080/resource/` then what should be an appropriate
   response to this request. Should it be 400 or 404 ?

   ***Please note that there is no Service hosted for `GET` `http://localhost:8080/resource/`***
2. `GET` `http://localhost:8080/users/{id}/history/` ==> that returns
   history details of user as per "id"

   So if client requests without "id" path parameter like `GET`
   `http://localhost:8080/users/history/` then what should be an appropriate
   response to this request. Should it be 400 or 404 ?

   ***Please note that there is no Service hosted for `GET` `http://localhost:8080/users/history/`***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if client requests without "id" path parameter like GET http://localhost:8080/resource/ then what should be an appropriate response to this request. Should it be 400 or 404 ?

[404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

- That's the error code that calls the caller's attention to the effective request uri specifically
- 404 is cacheable by default.  You want clients and proxies to remember and reuse the 404 response.  You don't get that behavior with 400 (which can cover a wide variety of problems).

Same argument holds for both of your examples.